# Is there an elegant and concise way to encode PHP heredocs in EBNF?

Tags: php, parsing, grammar, ebnf

Here is the documentation for [heredocs](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). I could only think of a verbose, obscure and not even completely general character by character comparison.

Comment: How you've done it until now?

Comment: The question isn't clear.   Does OP intend to *parse* a heredoc with EBNF? or something else?